# How can I diff a tree and a remote branch in git?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-diff-tree

I need to diff two objects in git. One is a tree (directory) in my working directory, and the other one is a remote branch. I can do so if I find the SHA of the tree and use that in the argument of my git diff command along with the remote branch. However, I am trying to find a way not to have to dig in the SHA first.

So, for example, if:

```
My_Working_Dir
  file1
  file2
  Dir1
    file3
    file4

remote_branch/master
  file3
  file4
```

Then I like to be able to issue something like this:

```
git diff Dir1  remote_branch/master
```

This works if I replace Dir1 with its SHA, but not if I just try to use the directory name. I have tried to use diff-tree as well. But that is not helping either. Please note that the remote_branch/master does not have the Dir1 directory.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<branch>:<file_path>` notation with `git diff`

`git diff remote_branch/master:file3 HEAD:Dir1/file3`

`git diff remote_branch/master:file4 HEAD:Dir1/file4`

Comment: Wonderful. Since I have many files I noticed the following works git diff remote_branch HEAD:Dir1

Comment: O ok, nice.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the path argument after the `--`.

I.e.

`git diff remote_branch/master -- Dir1`

Comment: Thanks Jiri, I tried this. However, from the output, it appears that it behaves as if the files in Dir1 (corresponding to the files in the remote_branch) are empty. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I think I know why this is not working. The command assumes the path exist in both HEAD and remote_branch/master. While it is true that it exists in the HEAD, for my case, it does not exist in remote_branch/master.